# Random Binary Matrix where Rows and Columns Sum to 1 using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

I want to generate a random `n x n` binary matrix using NumPy, where:

- each value is either `0` or `1`
- every row sums up to `1`
- every column sums up to `1`

For example, a valid matrix might be

```py
[[1 0 0]
[0 0 1]
[0 1 0]]
```

while an invalid one is

```py
[[1 0 0]
[0 0 1]
[0 0 1]]
```

I tried doing the following, but I couldn't figure out how to shuffle the values in each column using a unique index. How do I generate a matrix that adheres to the above constraints?

```py
N = 10
a = np.zeros((N,N))
a[0,:] = 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an `n` by `n` identity matrix, and then shuffle all of the rows. The identity matrix is a binary matrix where each row and column sums to one, and shuffling the rows preserves this property:

```py
n = 5
result = np.identity(n)
np.random.shuffle(result)
print(result)
```

This will output something like:

```py
[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`np.random.permutation`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html) to create random column indices and then use [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html?highlight=advanced%20indexing#advanced-indexing) fill indices with 1s:

```
N = 10
a = np.zeros((N,N), dtype=int)

a[np.arange(N), np.random.permutation(N)] = 1

a
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```