# Random matrix with sum of values by column = 1 in python

Tags: python, numpy, math, matrix, random

Create a matrix like a transtision matrix
How i can create random matrix with sum of values by column = 1 in python ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random Binary Matrix where Rows and Columns Sum to 1 using Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71719393/random-binary-matrix-where-rows-and-columns-sum-to-1-using-numpy)

Answer (score 3):

(**EDIT**: added output)

I suggest completing this in two steps:

1. Create a random matrix
2. Normalize each column

**1. Create random matrix**

Let's say you want a 3 by 3 random transition matrix:

```py
M = np.random.rand(3, 3)
```

Each of `M`'s entries will have a random value between 0 and 1.

**Normalize `M`'s columns**

By dividing each column by the column sum will achieve what you want. This can be done in several ways, but I prefer to create an array `r` whose elements is the column sum of `M`:

```py
r = M.sum(axis=0)
```

Then, divide `M` by `r`:

```py
transition_matrix = M / r
```

**Example output**

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> M = np.random.rand(3,3 )
>>> r = M.sum(axis=0)
>>> transition_matrix = M / r

>>> M
array([[0.74145687, 0.68389986, 0.37008102],
       [0.81869654, 0.0394523 , 0.94880781],
       [0.93057194, 0.48279246, 0.15581823]])
>>> r
array([2.49072535, 1.20614462, 1.47470706])
>>> transition_matrix
array([[0.29768713, 0.56701315, 0.25095223],
       [0.32869804, 0.03270943, 0.64338731],
       [0.37361483, 0.40027743, 0.10566046]])
>>> transition_matrix.sum(axis=0)
array([1., 1., 1.])
```

Comment: You recognize that distribution of those numbers would be ... what?

Comment: As described in the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.rand.html), `numpy.random.rand` uses a uniform distribution over [0, 1).

Comment: and what kind of distribution would be for values (in simplest case of 2x2 matrix) like X1/(X1+X2) where X1,X2 are both U(0,1) ? I put update in my answer to discuss the problem

Answer (score 1):

You could use KNOWN distribution where each sample would have (by default) summed to one, e.g. [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution).

After that code is basically one liner, Python 3.8, Windows 10 x64

```
import numpy as np

N = 3

# set alphas array, 1s by default
a = np.empty(N)
a.fill(1.0)

mtx = np.random.dirichlet(a, N).transpose()

print(mtx)
```

and it will print something like

```
[[0.56634637 0.04568052 0.79105779]
 [0.42542107 0.81892862 0.02465906]
 [0.00823256 0.13539087 0.18428315]]
```

UPDATE

For the case of "sample something and normalize", problem is one would get value from unknown distribution. For Dirichlet there are expressions for mean, std.dev, PDF, CDF, you name it.

Even for the case with X<sub>i</sub> sampled from U(0,1) what would be distribution of values for X<sub>i</sub>/Sum(i, X<sub>i</sub>).

Anything to say about mean? std.dev? PDF? Other stat properties?

You could sample from exponential and get sum normalized to 1, but
question would be even more acute - if X<sub>i</sub> is Exp(1), what is the distribution for X<sub>i</sub>/Sum(i, X<sub>i</sub>) ? PDF? Mean? Std.dev?